# how to push element into array at specific index in loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

When i try:

```
for (index = 0; index < results[1].length; ++index) {
          results[1].splice(index,0,{Keys:"Test"}); 
}
```

the code crashes - it adds more element to an array and the loop is going endless

Comment: *"the code crashes"* with which error? Modifying the array while iterating over it usually causes problems (unless done right).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the code crashes - it adds more element to an array and the loop is
>   going endless

Because `index < results[1].length` never fails as you keep on increasing the length of `result` by adding elements to it.

make it

```
var length = results[1].length;
for (index = 0; index < length; ++index) {
    results[1].splice( index, 0, {Keys:"Test"} ); 
}
```

Also, this will keep pointing the `index` to the newly added item, so increase the `index` as well

```
for (index = 0; index < results[1].length; index = index + 2) 
{
    results[1].splice( index, 0, {Keys:"Test"} ); 
}
```

Comment: This will not iterate over the last N element where N is the number of newly inserted item, isn't it?

Comment: The second one will not iterate over all original elements either.

Comment: OP hasn't mentioned about *iterate over last N element*. What did I missed?

Comment: Presumably the OP wants to insert a new element for each existing element in the array. Neither of your examples is doing that.

Comment: @FelixKling Second one will only iterate over the existing elements, and will ensure that index doesn't points to the element which is just inserted.

Comment: @gurvinder372: That would require to update `length` as well. Or keep `index < results[1].length;`.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, I missed that part. Thanks for pointing it out.